# SQL Server: "if not exists... create index" pattern fails "because an index or statistics already exists"

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I need reliable code to say "create index if it doesn't already exist."

I thought I had it:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM sys.indexes 
               WHERE name = 'IX_GraphedTripleValueBit_PropertyDefinitionId' 
                 AND object_id = OBJECT_ID('internal_dot_dotalign_dot_com_teams_1.GraphedTripleValueBit')) 
BEGIN 
    CREATE INDEX IX_GraphedTripleValueBit_PropertyDefinitionId 
    ON internal_dot_dotalign_dot_com_teams_1.GraphedTripleValueBit(PropertyDefinitionId) 
    INCLUDE (GraphedEntityRootUid) 
END;
```

Yet I get this error:

> The operation failed because an index or statistics with name 'IX_GraphedTripleValueBit_PropertyDefinitionId' already exists on table 'GraphedTripleValueBit'

Am I required to check `sys.indexes` and also check `sys.stats`? (like [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/736e4673-f812-4f0c-8c3b-4862fdc8933e/proper-way-to-check-for-an-existing-index?forum=transactsql)?)

Our SQL is code-generated (C#, not Entity Framework) and runs against the client's SQL Azure DB upon deployment. So at least until their DBA comes online to give access, I can't get in there easily for a first-hand look at the sys tables. Also, there are many of these tables so I don't want to incur extra overhead on checks unless needed (though as of now checking sys.stats is my leading theory). So wanted to ask here.

Thoughts?

Comment: The only reason to check `sys.stats` is if you've explicitly created statistics with the same name as the index in the past. Does your code generate `CREATE STATISTICS` too? If so, perhaps that's the culprit for the conflicting name, although I wouldn't expect a prefix of `IX_` to be specified for a statistics name.

Comment: Maybe a good idea to drop the stats in the same code and recreate it under a more conventional name?

Comment: I don't call CREATE STASTICS. Whatever's there happened implicitly, not via my code. I don't use EF either (i.e. all T-SQL is written by my code).

Comment: Try to put the create inside `sys.sp_executesql`, in case the parser is trying to outsmart you. Also, please don’t try to reduce overhead by minimizing metadata checks. Safety and accuracy are way more important than the 7 microseconds that might save you (or worse later if being lazy about checks leads to multiple redundant indexes). It’s just not the place to optimize, like leaving your hat at home because the extra weight will reduce your gas mileage.

Comment: I can't repro. But your mention of "client's SQL Azure DB" makes me think that this is a permissions problem. That is, your `not exists` check returns null because the account under which it runs does not have permission to see that metadata. Though looking at the docs for sys.indexes, it seems like the only requirement is that you have any other permission on the table or view (or be the owner of the same, but that's a superset).

Comment: Aaron, re the metadata checks, the more I think about it - Like Dan said it seems unlikely that there would be some auto-creation of a statistic that has an IX_ prefix (again, I didn't make statistics deliberately). I may try the sp_executesql if nothing else works, though it would be unsettling (no conceptual reason why this particular T-SQL needs it).

Comment: Ben, re permissions, this account should have all permissions. It's also the account that created the table.

Comment: But there _is_ a conceptual reason why some scripts might require dynamic SQL: in some cases (again I am traveling and don't have a computer handy) the parser first checks the script to make sure you aren't referencing an index that already exists - the parser is trying to be smart, but it's not smart enough to check conditionals like `IF`. So it could fail on certain things _at parse time_, not _at runtime_, but I don't believe that's happening here. What does `SELECT name FROM sys.indexes WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'internal_dot_dotalign_dot_com_teams_1.GraphedTripleValueBit');` return?

Comment: And really stop worrying about the stats. I seriously doubt this has anything to do with statistics, it's just that the error message is overloaded.

Comment: I'll stop worrying about the stats; sounds good. I need help from the client's DBA to access the server to run that SELECT; will do. Re "dynamic SQL", my app dynamically generates T-SQL extensively based on C# conditions (if that's what you meant). Are you saying that all dynamic SQL should be called via sys.sp_executesql? Right now I simply create a SqlCommand object in C# and call its ExecuteNonQueryAsync method. It sounds like your saying the command text should be wrapped in sys.sp_executesql every time? 

Meanwhile I wonder if perhaps Polly snuck in a dupe call after the IF was checked?

Comment: No. I'm saying that in some cases you're going to need C# to send `sys.sp_executesql` calls to SQL Server. That's all. I have no idea what Polly is, I just know that sometimes SQL Server will barf on a reference even though there is conditional logic that it can't see _during parsing_.

Answer (score 1):

Upon closer inspection, it seems like there were too instances of the application attempting to migrate the same table. Presumably, the IF NOT EXISTS condition was checked at a moment when that was a true statement, but by the time it executed the CREATE statement, there was already a conflicting index.